# I can't attach scripts to a GameObject Unity 2020.3.33f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I try to attach a script to a game object ( whether via dragging or add Component ) It always returns this error saying, "Can't add script component'scipt' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match." Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: BTW, this message is also shown if your script has compilation errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You checked editor console? No error logs? If yes attach console log with errors here
2. Check name your script, one of the classes in this script must named by file name
   Example: `MyClass.cs` contains `public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Nope no nothing, I literally created a new script with no errors or anything, and tried to attach it to a GameObject and it said that the script didn't exist

Comment: Script inherit MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Ye it also inherits from MonoBehaviour

Answer (score 0):

1.Your Class should inherit MonoBehaviour, otherwise it can't attach to a GameObject.

2.The file name should be same as the class name

Here's an example:

```
using UnityEngine;
public MyClass:MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start(){}
    void Update(){}
}
```